# Analytical solution to the covariance between a continuous and a categorical variable

Tags: categorical-data, expected-value, covariance, covariance-matrix, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a continuous variable with mean $\mu$ and $Y$ be a categorical variable with event probability vector $\mathbf{p}$. I am trying to calculate $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)$.

I have the solution if $\mathbf{p} = p_1$, i.e., $Y$ is binary. Using the law of total expectation:

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)
&= E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) \\
&= E(XY | Y = 0) p_0 + E(XY | Y = 1) p_1 - \mu p_1 \\
&= E(X0 | Y = 0) p_0 + E(X1 | Y = 1) p_1 - \mu p_1 \\
&= E(0 | Y = 0) p_0 + E(X | Y = 1) p_1 - \mu p_1 \\
&= 0 + E(X | Y = 1) p_1 - \mu p_1 \\
&= E(X | Y = 1) p_1 - \mu p_1
\end{align}
$$

The operations above assume $E(Y) = p_1$, $p_0 = 1 - p_1$ and $E(0 | Y = 0) p_0 = E(0) p_0 = 0 p_0 = 0$.

However, if $Y$ is polytomous, I think I am making some mistake in my calculations, because when I simulate data the observed covariance is very different from the analytical solution. For $\mathbf{p} = \{p_1, p_2\}$, I have

$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y),
$$

where

$$
E(X)E(Y) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu  p_1 \\
\mu  p_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
E(XY) 
&= E(XY | Y = 0) p_0 + E(XY | Y = 1) p_1 + E(XY | Y = 2) p_2\\
&= E(X0 | Y = 0) p_0 + E(X1 | Y = 1) p_1 + E(X2 | Y = 2) p_2\\
&= E(0 | Y = 0) p_0 + E(X | Y = 1) p_1 + 2E(X | Y = 2) p_2\\
&= 0 + E(X | Y = 1) p_1 + 2E(X | Y = 2) p_2\\
&= E(X | Y = 1) p_1 + 2E(X | Y = 2) p_2
.\end{align}
$$

For a general case of $i$ categories, this generalizes to

$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y) = \sum_{i} i E(X | Y = i) p_i.
$$

I can already see a problem here because the solution above is a scalar, whereas the $E(X)E(Y)$ above is a vector, so I can't just subtract one from the other. In any case, if I set $\mu = 0$, I get rid of $E(X)E(Y)$ but the results still don't match, which makes me think $E(XY)$ is problematic by itself.

I guess I am also getting a bit lost in the fact that for a binary $Y$ the categories are 0 and 1, whereas a polytomous $Y$ has categories 1, 2, 3... (no zero).

Comment: I'm having to make guesses about what much of your terminology means, so please let me know whether I have misunderstood.  Around the middle of this post you appear to take the *probability distribution* of $Y$ (your "event probability vector") to be the expectation of $Y,$ but those two are completely different things.  In particular, $E[Y] = \sum_{i=1} i p_i$ is a scalar, not a vector.

Comment: @whuber, I think you understood it correctly. Going from binomial to polynomial is making me embarrassingly confused.

Comment: 1. You seem to be using Y in two different ways. If Y takes values 1,2,3 ... which indicate a *nominal category* (1=red M&M,2=brown M&M,3=green M&M, etc) - its values are factor-levels - it makes no sense to treat Y a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Standard_case), so things like expectation or correlation directly on the values of Y doesn't make sense (the labels are arbitrary, for a start, we could as easily have chosen 1=green, 2=red, ... etc). Can you explain the underlying problem/variable more clearly? ... ctd

Comment: 2. when you go from a binary variable to having more than two categories, the counts of the number in each outcome (the equivalent of binomial but with a vector of counts, one for each possible outcome) is *multinomial* rather than *polynomial*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may not be the most straightforward solution, but intuitively it worked for me, and my simulations also show this works.

So if $Y$ is polynomial, it can be broken down into several binary variables. For example, if $\mathbf{p} = \{p1, p2\}$ instead of working out $Cov(X, Y)$, we can work out $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y_1)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y_2)$ separately, where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are Bernoulli-distributed with parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively. So, for $i = 1, 2$:

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y_i)
&= E(XY_i) - E(X)E(Y_i) \\
&= E(XY_i | Y_i = 0) (1 - p_i) + E(XY | Y_i = 1) p_i - \mu p_i \\
&= E(X0 | Y_i = 0) (1 - p_i) + E(X1 | Y_i = 1) p_i- \mu p_i \\
&= E(0 | Y_i = 0) (1 - p_i) + E(X | Y_i = 1) p_i - \mu p_i \\
&= 0 + E(X | Y_i = 1) p_i - \mu p_i \\
&= E(X | Y_i = 1) p_i - \mu p_i
.\end{align}
$$

Note that $Y_i = \{0, 1\}$, so it doesn't matter how the categories are labeled (starting from zero, starting from one, centered in zero, etc.).

This means that $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)$ is actually a vector, composed as

$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y_1) \\
\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y_2)
\end{bmatrix},
$$

It should be noted that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are correlated with covariance equal to $-p_1 p_2$. Moreover, the extension of the above to more categories is straightforward.